# How to fetch, display Amazon Marketplace listings by item?

Tags: e-commerce, amazon-web-services

My question pretty much says it all: I'm looking for a way to display Amazon Marketplace listings based on an item lookup. Example: If I do a call to ItemLookup with an ASIN of 0590353403 (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone), I'm looking for a result set of perhaps the top ten new or used Marketplace listings, preferably with seller information attached.

I apologize if this is clearly documented somewhere, but I have been looking all through the Amazon API docs and on Google to no avail. StackOverflow doesn't seem to have any Related Questions that match what I'm asking, either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further research, it seems I've found what I was looking for. In order to get a listing of all sale offers -- not just those from Amazon itself -- you must specify the MerchantId parameter in your query to the web service. This parameter can take on a few different values: "Amazon" (default), "All," "Featured," or a specific Merchant ID.

To get all the offer information, including seller names and the like, you must also submit the parameter ResponseGroup with the value "OfferFull."

Hope this helps somebody else out down the line! :-)